# How to add a fake ethernet header to a capture

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packets, wireshark-dissector

I have a decrypted VPN pcap file. What I am trying to do is to read the pcap using tcptrace in linux. But, tcptrace does not seem to get this format that I have. 
So here is the snapshot of the pcap. [This is the pcap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOQXW.jpg)

So, what I want to do is to remove the 12 bytes, ENC header and then add a 14 byte ethernet header there.

I am not sure how to do that. I would typically like to separate a pcap that contains only requests and add a ethernet header after removing 12 bytes of ENC header. 
Similarly create a pcap for reply's.

Can someone please help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If `tcptrace` can handle pcap files with [Linktype Raw](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html), then you can use [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) to strip the first 12 bytes from the packets and not even bother with adding a dummy Ethernet header if you save the file with the `rawip` encapsulation.  For example:

```
editcap infile.pcapng outfile.pcap -L -C 12 -T rawip -F pcap
```

Note: Here I used the `-F pcap` option to force the output file to be saved as a pcap file instead of a pcapng file, because I don't know if `tcptrace` supports pcapng files or not, and pcapng is the default output file type that `editcap` uses if you don't specify the output file type.

If `tcptrace` does not support Linktype Raw, then you should still be able to accomplish what you need, but you'll have to take the output file generated from `editcap` above and manipulate it further.  Since `editcap` itself doesn't support adding a dummy Ethernet header to the packets, you can use Wireshark to save the packets to a text file and then convert the text file back to a pcap file, but when you convert it back to a pcap file, you will have the option of adding a dummy Ethernet header to the packets.  That last step can also be accomplished with [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html).  Here are the steps to follow using Wireshark:

1. Load the outfile.pcap file: File -> Open... -> File name: outfile.pcap.
2. Temporarily disable the IPv4 protocol.  This is to ensure that reassembly does not occur; otherwise the output text file will not be generated in a format suitable to be imported later on should any reassembly occur: Analyze -> Enabled Protocols -> Protocols -> IPv4 -> De-select -> Apply.
3. Remove or hide all columns and add an absolute time column.  This allows you to export the timestamp, and while not strictly required, it is very useful: Edit -> Preferences -> Columns -> De-select all columns; Add -> Field type: Absolute date, as YYYY-MM-DD, and time; Title "AbsTime" -> OK.  (Note: It might be easier to create a separate [Profile](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustConfigProfilesSection.html) for "Pcap2Text" purposes in which only this column is displayed.  This allows you to quickly change to this profile whenever you want to perform this operation again without affecting the columns of any other working profile.)
4. Export the packets to a text file: File -> Export Packet Dissections -> as "Plain Text" file... -> File name: outfile.txt; Packet Range: All packets; Packet Format: Select Packet summary line (but not column headings) and Packet Bytes.
5. Re-enable the IPv4 protocol: Analyze -> Enabled Protocols -> Protocols -> IPv4 -> Select -> OK.
6. Close the original output.pcap file.
7. Import the output.txt text file: File -> Import from Hex Dump... -> Filename: output.txt; Offsets: Hexadecimal; Date/Time: Select; Format: "%F %T." (no quotes, but the trailing '.' is important - this is the default); Import Encapsulation type: Ethernet; Dummy header: Select; Ethernet Ethertype (hex): 0800 -> OK.
8. Save the file: File -> Save As... -> File name: newfile_with_dummy_ethernet_header.pcap, Save as type: Wireshark/tcpdump/...- pcap (*.pcap;*.pcap.gz;*.cap;*.cap.gz;*.dmp;*.dmp.gz)

This file should now be readable by `tcptrace`.  I can't promise that this is the most expedient method to achieve your goal, but at least it works in creating a pcap file with Ethernet encapsulation that `tcptrace` should be able to read.

Disclaimer: These instructions were generated using Wireshark 1.12.13 running on Windows 7 64-bit, or more specifically:

```
Compiled (64-bit) with GTK+ 2.24.23, with Cairo 1.10.2, with Pango 1.34.0, with
GLib 2.38.0, with WinPcap (4_1_3), with libz 1.2.5, with SMI 0.4.8, with c-ares
1.9.1, with Lua 5.2, without Python, with GnuTLS 3.2.15, with Gcrypt 1.6.2,
without Kerberos, with GeoIP, with PortAudio V19-devel (built Jul 28 2016), with
AirPcap.

Running on 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1, build 7601, with WinPcap version
4.1.3 (packet.dll version 4.1.0.2980), based on libpcap version 1.0 branch
1_0_rel0b (20091008), GnuTLS 3.2.15, Gcrypt 1.6.2, with AirPcap 4.1.3 build
3348.
       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GHz, with 8072MB of physical memory.

Built using Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 build 30319
```